# The Bar Is Rising

Tags: meaning

What does "the bar is rising" mean in this sentence?

"The Bar Is Rising on Sustainability Leadership."
(https://corpgov.law.harvard.edu/2013/02/06/the-bar-is-rising-on-sustainability-leadership/)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It means that the standard is getting higher.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I take" the standard is getting hier" fits the best, but it can have slightly different meanings depending on the situation.

Comment: Well, yes:  if you're in a pub, and a magician causes the counter to levitate, then it *would* have a different meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+the+bar+(high%2Flow)) idiom

**set the bar (high/low)**

> To establish an expected, required, or desired standard of quality.
>   (Often said of a standard that is constrictive in being either too low
>   or too high).

As in:

> "The Bar Is Rising on Sustainability Leadership."

aka:

... sustainable leadership is becoming harder to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The *bar* is a metaphor of a hurdle that must be jumped over to continue the competition.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hurdle

[image]

Thus, *raising the bar* means the situation has become more difficult, especially for the less skilled competitors.